# Different Representations of Scala HashMap

Tags: scala, hashmap

I've been playing around with the Scala HashMap and I've noticed two different representations of the HashMap. I was wondering if somebody could explain the difference of:

```
Map(123 -> 1)
```

and

```
{123=1}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know `val m = Map ((123, 1),(456, 2))`?

Answer (score 5):

Where have you seen `{123=1}`?  It's not a standard representation in Scala, but it *is* the way Java defines `toString` for its Maps.

```
val sm = Map(1->1, 2->2) // Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)

val jm = new java.util.HashMap[Int,Int]()
jm.put(1,1)
jm.put(2,2)
jm   
// java.util.HashMap[Int,Int] = {1=1, 2=2}
```

Comment: sorry I figured it out. {123=1} occurs when you're using the java.util.HashMap as opposed to the scala one.

Answer (score 2):

`->` is a method that creates tuples. By itself it doesn't directly have anything to do with maps. So for example `123 -> 1` returns a tuple `(123, 1)`. You can try this in the REPL:

```
scala> 123 -> 1
res1: (Int, Int) = (123,1)
```

You can create a map by supplying tuples to `object Map`'s `apply` method, which is what you are doing when you do this:

```
val m = Map(123 -> 1, 456 -> 2)
```

is the same as

```
val m = Map.apply(123 -> 1, 456 -> 2)
```

is the same as

```
val m = Map.apply((123, 1), (456, 2))
```

which creates a `Map` with two entries, one with key `123` and value `1`, the other one with key `456` and value `2`.